# Importing table into database (DB2)

Tags: xml, database, db2, relational-database

I have a table which contains an XML type column. I make export for this table using IXF format. when I tried to make import for this table, it gives me error saying you may use File Type Modifier (FORCECREATE) or You should use db2look tool to extract information from the table then make Insert.
I do not know how to use File Type Modifier (FORCECREATE)? Can anyone expalin?

What is db2look tool? where can I find this tool? How to use it? I searched alot but no website talks about those tools!

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote could have several possible causes. Without the concrete error message it's hard to find the exact problem. On this page you find several problems that require the use of FORCECREATE: [Link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/c0024693.htm)

With that you might be able to correct the cause and don't need to use FORCECREATE or DB2LOOK.

---

Import with FORCECREATE:

The modifier is just an parameter for the import-command:

```
db2 import from <file> of ixf modified by forcecreate replace_create into <tab>
```

You can get an short reference for the import-command in the commandline:

```
db2 ? import
```

Or read the details in IBMs very comprehensive [online docmentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0008304.htm)

---

DB2LOOK-Tool:

The db2look-tool ist part of db2 (at least in v.9.5 on windows). Just enter `db2look` in commandline, if it is installed you get short parameter overview. Again, the IBM online documentation would provide you with detailed information.